# How ti detect browser if refresh or close or new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey I am counting the time spent by user in the page.
My problem is how to detect if the page  refresh or is open a new tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For handling refresh you can use the `window.onbeforeunload` and write a function.
- For new tab you can use the `window.onblur` and write a function.

Both these hooks are compatible across all the major browsers Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge and IE.

Comment: just question  in this function it requires a return
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
but me when reload the page I want to send data

Comment: Yes, You'll have to implement localStorage and update to your server after the page has reloaded. All APIs will be cancelled when page reloads.

Comment: if I want to work with  $(window).on('beforeunload', function

how do I hide the dialog box

Comment: it is resolved i add return undefined

Answer (score 2):

```
if (window.performance) {
  console.info("window.performance works fine on this browser");
}
  if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
  } else {
    console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
  }
```

Comment: It's not compatible for all browser

Comment: @Antoinecoulibaly you didn't mention in the question which browser you were testing on

Comment: Yes, please elaborate more when you ask question.

Comment: @RenatoManalili Generally speaking, we always look for the code for all browsers

Comment: "*all browsers*" Lynx? IE4? curl? Microsoft Visual Studio internal web browser (probably uses IE)?  Baidu?  https://caniuse.com/#search=performance